Stop MoveTo Block to take shortest path in anylogic
I have three nodes, let us say A, B, and C. Now I want to go from A to C.
The shortest route in order to reach from A to C is A to B to C, which the MoveTo block is taking. However, I don't want to take that route; I want to take a specific route, in this case a long route. How can I achieve this?
I want the agent to reach a specific node using a specific path, as sometimes the shortest path will be the correct one.


you need to have intermediate nodes... no other way with standards paths... the selection of the route is out of your control

If you want full control, you need to implement your own path-finding, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/agentify-your-network-pathfinding
